# Neo4j increasing latency as SKIP increases on Cypher query + REST API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My setup:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
Neo4j 2.0.0-M06 Enterprise
```

First I made sure I warmed up the cache by executing the following:

```
START n=node(*) RETURN COUNT(n);
START r=relationship(*) RETURN count(r);
```

The size of the table is 63,677 nodes and 7,169,995 relationships

Now I have the following query:

```
START u1=node:node_auto_index('uid:39')
MATCH (u1:user)-[w:WANTS]->(c:card)<-[h:HAS]-(u2:user)
WHERE u2.uid <> 39
WITH u2.uid AS uid, (CASE WHEN w.qty < h.qty THEN w.qty ELSE h.qty END) AS have
RETURN uid, SUM(have) AS total
ORDER BY total DESC
SKIP 0
LIMIT 25
```

This UID has about 40k+ results that I want to be able to put a pagination to. The initial skip was around `773ms`. I tried page 2 (skip 25) and the latency was around the same even up to page 500 it only rose up to `900ms` so I didn't really bother. Now I tried some fast forward paging and jumped by thousands so I did 1000, then 2000, then 3000. I was hoping the ORDER BY arrangement will already have been cached by Neo4j and using `SKIP` will just move  to that index in the result and wont have to iterate through each one again. But for each thousand skip I made the latency increased by alot. It's not just cache warming because for one I already warmed up the cache and two, I tried the same skip a couple of times for each skip and it yielded the same results:

```
SKIP    0:  773ms
SKIP 1000: 1369ms
SKIP 2000: 2491ms
SKIP 3000: 3899ms
SKIP 4000: 5686ms
SKIP 5000: 7424ms
```

Now who the hell would want to view 5000 pages of results? 40k even?! :) Good point! I will probably put a cap on the maximum results a user can view but I was just curious about this phenomenon. Will somebody please explain why Neo4j seems to be re-iterating through stuff which appears to be already known to it?

Here is my profiling for the 0 skip:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["uid", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE65c4d6a2-1930-4f32-8fd9-5e4399ce6f14"], returnItemNames=["uid", "total"], _rows=25, _db_hits=0)
==> Slice(skip="Literal(0)", _rows=25, _db_hits=0)
==>   Top(orderBy=["SortItem(Cached(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE65c4d6a2-1930-4f32-8fd9-5e4399ce6f14 of type Any),false)"], limit="Add(Literal(0),Literal(25))", _rows=25, _db_hits=0)
==>     EagerAggregation(keys=["uid"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE65c4d6a2-1930-4f32-8fd9-5e4399ce6f14,Sum(have))"], _rows=41659, _db_hits=0)
==>       ColumnFilter(symKeys=["have", "u1", "uid", "c", "h", "w", "u2"], returnItemNames=["uid", "have"], _rows=146826, _db_hits=0)
==>         Extract(symKeys=["u1", "c", "h", "w", "u2"], exprKeys=["uid", "have"], _rows=146826, _db_hits=587304)
==>           Filter(pred="((NOT(Product(u2,uid(0),true) == Literal(39)) AND hasLabel(u1:user(0))) AND hasLabel(u2:user(0)))", _rows=146826, _db_hits=146826)
==>             TraversalMatcher(trail="(u1)-[w:WANTS WHERE (hasLabel(NodeIdentifier():card(1)) AND hasLabel(NodeIdentifier():card(1))) AND true]->(c)<-[h:HAS WHERE (NOT(Product(NodeIdentifier(),uid(0),true) == Literal(39)) AND hasLabel(NodeIdentifier():user(0))) AND true]-(u2)", _rows=146826, _db_hits=293696)
```

And for the 5000 skip:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["uid", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE99329ea5-03cd-4d53-a6bc-3ad554b47872"], returnItemNames=["uid", "total"], _rows=25, _db_hits=0)
==> Slice(skip="Literal(5000)", _rows=25, _db_hits=0)
==>   Top(orderBy=["SortItem(Cached(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE99329ea5-03cd-4d53-a6bc-3ad554b47872 of type Any),false)"], limit="Add(Literal(5000),Literal(25))", _rows=5025, _db_hits=0)
==>     EagerAggregation(keys=["uid"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE99329ea5-03cd-4d53-a6bc-3ad554b47872,Sum(have))"], _rows=41659, _db_hits=0)
==>       ColumnFilter(symKeys=["have", "u1", "uid", "c", "h", "w", "u2"], returnItemNames=["uid", "have"], _rows=146826, _db_hits=0)
==>         Extract(symKeys=["u1", "c", "h", "w", "u2"], exprKeys=["uid", "have"], _rows=146826, _db_hits=587304)
==>           Filter(pred="((NOT(Product(u2,uid(0),true) == Literal(39)) AND hasLabel(u1:user(0))) AND hasLabel(u2:user(0)))", _rows=146826, _db_hits=146826)
==>             TraversalMatcher(trail="(u1)-[w:WANTS WHERE (hasLabel(NodeIdentifier():card(1)) AND hasLabel(NodeIdentifier():card(1))) AND true]->(c)<-[h:HAS WHERE (NOT(Product(NodeIdentifier(),uid(0),true) == Literal(39)) AND hasLabel(NodeIdentifier():user(0))) AND true]-(u2)", _rows=146826, _db_hits=293696)
```

The only difference is the LIMIT clause on the Top function. I hope we can make this work as intended, I really don't want to delve into doing an embedded Neo4j + my own Jetty REST API for the web app.

Comment: Do you see anything noteworthy if you profile the question in the neo4j-shell or console?

Comment: I added query profiles fro both 0 and 5000 skip. There doesnt seem to be much difference in the results. Only the limits in the Top function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are not cached, otherwise a lot of memory inside the server would be holding onto results that are very probably not used.

And as you state correctly, people are mostly interested in the first or first two pages and then refine their search.

If you need to have more predictable paging performance, pull more results out of neo in the firs place, stick them into your user session and serve them from there. You can do that with much more context information than the database (e.g. user behavior profiles or power-user flags etc).

Comment: I agree I may have asked too much. I guess pulling the results to a MongoDB collection and have an index on the aggregate value to sort it is not such a bad idea after all. I can have the results cached there and have the user pull new results in another 5 minutes.